# Can I install 8gb of memory to full Macbook 5,1 Ubuntu install?

Tags: uefi, hardware, mac, ram, macbook

Seems that 8gb of memory is not stable in original Macbook 5,1 if I'm not running "Mac OS X 10.6 "Snow Leopard" or higher and have Boot ROM Version MB51.007D.B03" (http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/macbook-unibody-faq/macbook-unibody-13-non-pro-how-to-upgrade-ram.html).

So I have only Ubuntu 14.04 installed and I found out that I'm running in Legacy mode. Boot ROM version seems to refer to EFI(?). If I have old  EFI-installed, does it affect my memory upgrade? If yes, how do I upgrade EFI?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong (never ran a mac myself), but your BIOS/grub setup should have no impact on your available memory.

You could always check by running `free -h` to see your memory allotment. But it seems that if you're not running in a VM then you should have access to your full system capabilities.